# animate incrementing UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, animation, grand-central-dispatch, swift2

I am trying to animate the values of an UILabel when the view appears. Therefor I have created this function.

```
private func animateIncrementUILabel(label: SpringLabel, labelValue: Int, animationPeriod: Float?)
{

    animationPeriod != nil ? animationPeriod! : 40

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {

        for (var i = 0; i < labelValue; i++)
        {
            usleep(UInt32(animationPeriod!)/100 * 1000000)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                label.text = String(i)
            })
        }

    })
}
```

but when calling this in my viewDidAppear method like

```
animateIncrementUILabel(counterLabelOne, labelValue: 20, animationPeriod: 40.0)
```

it shows the value straight away in the label without the "animated incremention".

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Remove those dispatch blocks and use NSTimer.Schdule activity instead of sleep

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `usleep` and `dispatch_async` in this case. I'd recommend to you use `dispatch_after`:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(i * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    <#code to be executed after a specified delay#>
});
```

or NSTimer with repeat option

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Also you can pass some params to timer:

```
func someFunc(){
    var arr = ["one", "two"] 
    var timer: NSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("val:"), userInfo: arr, repeats: true)
}

func val(timer: NSTimer){

    //You'll get an array in timer.userInfo
    // arr = timer.userInfo.
    // Now you'll get you data in each index of arr

}
```

Comment: But I want to give several parameters along.. How do I achieve that with NSTimer? could you give an example?

Comment: but this way I can't force to give certain parameters. Its all optional